# Generation of Floating Cashflow using QuantLib in Python

Tags: python, finance, floating, quantlib

I'm having an issue with a Python program. I'm trying to generate cash flows using QuantLib, but I'm encountering a problem: my results are significantly different from those of Superderivatives or Bloomberg. Could you help me identify the error?

Thank you very much !

```
from QuantLib import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Parameters
start_date = Date(27, 2, 2015)
end_date = Date(27, 2, 2045)
face_value = 1900000
frequency = Semiannual  # semi-annual payments
spread_in_bp = -19.264
spread = spread_in_bp / 10000  # Convert from basis points to a decimal
calendar = UnitedKingdom()
schedule = Schedule(start_date, end_date, Period(frequency), calendar,
                    Following, Following, DateGeneration.Forward, False)

curve = pd.read_excel('USD_LIBOR_ZC-Curve.xlsx')

# Convertion
curve_dates = [Date(d) for d in curve['Date']]
curve_dates_numerical = [d.to_date().toordinal() for d in curve_dates]  # we need numerical dates for interpolation
curve_rates = [r/100 for r in curve['Rate']]  # Here we are assuming the rates are in percentage

# Create a zero curve and its handle
zero_curve = ZeroCurve(curve_dates, curve_rates, Actual360())
zero_curve_handle = YieldTermStructureHandle(zero_curve)

# 6-month LIBOR
reference_rate = USDLibor(Period(6, Months), zero_curve_handle)

# Add each interpolated fixing to the reference_rate
fixing_dates = [reference_rate.fixingDate(d) for d in schedule][:-1]  # get the fixing dates from the schedule
fixing_dates_numerical = [d.to_date().toordinal() for d in fixing_dates]  # we need numerical dates for interpolation
for fixing_date, fixing_date_num in zip(fixing_dates, fixing_dates_numerical):
    fixing_rate = np.interp(fixing_date_num, curve_dates_numerical, curve_rates)  # interpolate the rate
    reference_rate.addFixing(fixing_date, fixing_rate)

bond = FloatingRateBond(settlementDays=0, faceAmount=face_value, schedule=schedule,
                        index=reference_rate, paymentDayCounter=Actual360(), spreads=[spread])

# Evaluation of the bond using a discounting bond engine
bond_engine = DiscountingBondEngine(zero_curve_handle)
bond.setPricingEngine(bond_engine)

for i, cashflow in enumerate(bond.cashflows()):
    print(f"Cashflow {i + 1}: {cashflow.amount()} on {cashflow.date()}")

print(f"Bond's clean price: {bond.cleanPrice()}")
```

I tried to get the implied rate Rate but I don't really understand. I'm really confused...

Comment: Might help to add a few more details. What bond, what is the clean price that is quoted. Where is the spread from (and where do you get the zero curve from (and why is it in USD if you use UK calendar...). What exactly do you mean by getting the implied rate? Seems to me you just try to get compute the (clean) price.

Comment: Also not sure it is best to ask this here anyways. There is [quant se](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions) where people should know more about bond pricing. The coding isn't really a problem here.